# How to fix type mismatch in ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I don't know how to fix this error of arrayadapter parameter, it shows me this error :

`Type mismatch. Required:(Mutable)List<TypeVariable(T)!> Found: ArrayList<String!>?`

It's only happening when I transfer the ArrayList of strings from the main activity to another.

```
class playerList2 : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_list3)
    var intent = intent
    var liste = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("players")
    val adapt = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,liste)
    listView.adapter = adapt
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For the future - don't upload the code as an image - there are special formattings to paste your code in every language you can imagine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's cause "liste" could be null, take a look at the final "?" of ArrayList<String!>?
The adapter expects a non nullable list, you can check first if the ArrayList is not null and then use it or, the easy way if you are sure the array will always bring information use this:

```
val adapt = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste!!)
```

The secure way would be:

```
liste?.let{
  val adapt = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, it)
}
```

Or, as @cactustictacs indicate, this would be the most correct way:

```
val adapt = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste ?: emptyList())
```

I recomend to use the secure way always!

Comment: +1 for the secure way. Also, I think it's a good way to not make List types as nullable - you can easily pass an empty list and get no errors on looping through it.

Comment: Another way is to go ``val adapt = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste ?: emptyList())`` - the elvis operator gives you the second value if the first is null, so you can use it as a fallback. This way you're always initialising the adapter either way, just with a safe default! (might need to be an empty mutable list depending on what you're gonna do with it though)

Comment: ArrayAdapter only accepts NON-NULL type list, so "!!" applied.